# tkinter frame not filling empty space?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make list box of same size and expand `music_box_label` to empty space. tried `grid(sticky = "nsw"`on both `list_box_frame` and `list_box`, `grid(sticky = "nsew")`on music_box_label to expand to remaining size. i also tried giving weight to both label but i did't work. so what im doing wrong.

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("RHYTHM")
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "image/mp3_logo.png")
root.iconphoto(False, photo)

class main_window():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        
        #creating label frame for buttons(top frame)
        self.label_frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.label_frame1.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        
        self.music_box= ttk.LabelFrame(self.root,text = "Music box")
        self.music_box.grid(row = 1,column = 1,sticky = "nsew")
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.root,1,weight = 1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.root,1,weight = 1)
        
        self.list_box_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.root,text = "list box",width = 20)
        self.list_box_frame.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = "nsw")
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.root,1,weight = 2)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.root,0,weight = 2)
        
  
        
        #list box in first frame
        self.scroll_bar1 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.list_box_frame,orient = VERTICAL)
        self.scroll_bar1.grid(column = 1,sticky = "nsew")
        self.scroll_bar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.list_box_frame,orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.scroll_bar2.grid(row = 1,sticky = "nsew")
        
        self.list_box = tk.Listbox(self.list_box_frame,yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar1.set,xscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar2.set,width = 20)
        self.list_box.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = "nsw")
        
        self.scroll_bar1.config(command = self.list_box.yview)
        self.scroll_bar2.config(command = self.list_box.xview)
   
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.list_box_frame,0,weight = 1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.list_box_frame,0,weight = 1)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
```

[here is output image just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYB8G.png)

Comment: Please fix your indentations, and please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich i have edit my code please review again.

Comment: The code won't run as posted - it imports tkinter one way but uses it as if was imported differently. It's also missing an import for ttk. Also, it would help if you removed the image, unless the image is critical for reproducing the problem. Please make sure your example is runnable as posted.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, to get a widget to fill all available space when using `grid` requires two steps:

1. configure the row and/or column to have a positive `weight` so that extra space is allocated to the row or column, and
2. use the `sticky` attribute to cause the widget to fill the space allocated to it.

Pro tip: layout problems are much easier to visualize and to debug when all of the calls to `grid` or `pack` or `place` are grouped together.

This is how I would do it, assuming you want all extra space to go on the left. If you want the left and right (list box, music box) to both expand then you need to add weight to column 1.

```
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

self.label_frame1.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky="ew")
self.list_box_frame.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = "new")
self.music_box.grid(row = 1,column = 1,sticky = "nsew")
```

That takes care of the outer frames. You also need to make sure that the listbox expands to fill its space:

```
self.list_box.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = "nsew")
```